# Vue fullcalendar localization of header buttons

Tags: vue.js, localization, fullcalendar

I am hoping someone could help me out with fullcalendar locale. I am using Vue, and I have managed to localize everything in my calendar, except for the header buttons (screenshot attached). Here is the code:

```
  <calendar
  :datesAboveResources="true"
  :defaultView="calendarOptions.defaultView"
  :plugins="calendarOptions.plugins"
  :events="getEvents"
  :resources="resourcesOuter"
  :minTime="calendarOptions.minTime"
  :maxTime="calendarOptions.maxTime"
  :allDaySlot="calendarOptions.allDaySlot"
  :slotDuration="calendarOptions.slotDuration"
  :selectable="isSelectable"
  editable="true"
  :header="calendarOptions.header"
  :allDayDefault="calendarOptions.allDayDefault"
  @select="openCreateModal"
  @eventClick="openUpdateModal"
  @datesRender="onViewChange"
  @eventResize="eventResize"
  @eventDrop="eventDrop"
  id="calendar"
  ref="calendar"
  :locale="$i18n.locale"
  v-if="isDataLoaded"
  />
```

Here is the screenshot:

[fullcalendar localization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcjuH.png)

If more information is required, please do not hesitate to let me know.

Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: Which language are you trying to internationalise to? fullCalendar may not have a local entry for absolutely everything. (The localisation of dates is done by the native JS Date object, nothing to do with fullCalendar directly).

Comment: @ADyson For now, I would like to provide the user two options: english and slovenian.

Comment: `sl` is the language code for slovenian. Per the fullCalendar locale demo (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale-demo), if you set `sl` as the code, it should work (assuming you've included the locale module in your calendar). Examples provided at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale

Comment: Found a proper solution. 

Thank you so much @ADyson.

Comment: That's great. For the benefit of others - and the benefit of your own reputation if you receive upvotes - you should post your exact solution as an Answer below. You are encouraged to answer your own questions - it still helps the community (which is the purpose of Stackoverflow). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer for guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Like stated in the original post, I needed localization for two languages: English (which is default), and Slovenian. Here is how I achieved this.

First, I imported Slovenian locale to my script:

```
import slLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/sl'
```

Then, I imported this locale into `calendarOptions` object, under `locale` variable, like this:

```
locale: ((this.$i18n.locale === 'sl') ? slLocale : null)
```

Lastly, I set `:locale` attribute in the `<FullCalendar>`:

```
:locale="calendarOptions.locale"
```